# AlarmManager triggers way too soon

Tags: android, service, xamarin, background

I let my background service send the geo data of the device to an API.

```
private static long LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1800000;
```

Is supposed to be the interval for the location service and the `AlarmManager`.

The first alarm I fire in `MainActivity` like this

```
        Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(LocationService));
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 1, i, 
                                             PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService);
        alarm.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, 30000, pending);
```

Then, in the Service itself, I re-trigger the alarm all the time like this

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LocationService));
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 100, intent, 
                                             PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService);
        alarm.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, 
                       LOCATION_INTERVAL, pending);
```

Problem: The service gets called way too soon (+/- every minute!).

Question: How can I make my alarm manager stick to `LOCATION_INTERVAL`?

Comment: Whats the `onStartCommand()` of service returning?

Comment: @Shaishav This `return StartCommandResult.Sticky;`

Comment: Try it with NON_STICKY. Whatever the xamarin equivalet is.

Comment: Will try. Explanation please?

Comment: With sticky, the system may try to relaunch it if closed inappropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please check the solution below and let me know the results?

If does not work, I delete the answer....

**ISSUE**

I believe the error is here:

```
alarm.SetExact(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation);
```

> triggerAtMillis: time in milliseconds that the alarm should go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).

So, your are using `1800000` as triggerAtMillis. However, `1800000` is following date in UTC: `Thu Jan 01 1970 00:30:00`

Since this is an old date, the alarm is fired immediately.

**Solution**

Maybe, you should update your code as follows:

In MainActivity, I believe that you want to fire the alarm immediately. So, create it as follows:

```
alarm.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), pending);
```

In your service, it seems that you want to trigger your alarm after `1800000`. So, you have to use:

```
alarm.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + LOCATION_INTERVAL, pending);
```

This way, alarm will be fired 30 minutes after current time (current time + LOCATION_INTERVAL).

Keep in mind that second parameter is the date in milliseconds... It is a number which represents an whole date (and not only an interval)...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. The alarm never gets called.

Comment: But the alarm will be fired after 30 minutes... to test, you must decrease the interval...

Comment: Which interval? Location interval?

Comment: I updated the answer.. Hope it becomes clear. For now, your location interval is 30 minutes (1800000).. So, it seems that you want to trigger your alarm every 30 minutes... So, for test, you can reduce to a lower interval (like 3 minutes).. This way, you don't have to wait 30 minutes and see if the solution works

Comment: The service which will be fired includes a location listener with the interval of 5 seconds. When the service fires once every 30 mins, how should the location interval be?